# How can I print the longest sequence of the same element?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, sequence

I'm working on this homework assignment which asks to write a method called longestEqualSequence that determines the longest sequence of numbers that are equal. For example, in [6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 7, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7], the longest sequence is length three: 4, 4, 4. When I run the code below my output is "The longest sequence is length: 3" I want to also print the longest sequence which is [4, 4, 4]. How would I print the sequence along with the length of it?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] y = { 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));
        System.out.println("The longest sequence is length: " + longestEqualSequence(y));
        
    }

    public static int longestEqualSequence(int[] array) {
        int currentSequence = 1;
        int maxSequence = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {
                currentSequence++;
            } else {
                if (currentSequence > maxSequence) {
                    maxSequence = currentSequence;
                }
                currentSequence = 1;
            }
        }

        if (currentSequence > maxSequence)
            return currentSequence;
        else
            return maxSequence;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sequence_number variable and set it when currentSequence is greater than maxSequence.

```java
if (currentSequence > maxSequence) {
       maxSequence = currentSequence;
       sequence_number = array[i-1]
}
```

Then, print the sequence_number variable maxSequence times.

Comment: Where would I place this code? On what line?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a *current value* variable:

```
public static int[] longestEqualSequence(int[] array) {
    int currentSequence = 1;
    int maxSequence = 1;
    int currentValue = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {
            currentSequence++;
        } else {
            if (currentSequence > maxSequence) {
                maxSequence = currentSequence;
                currentValue = array[i - 1];
            }
            currentSequence = 1;
        }
    }

    int[] sequence = new int[currentSequence > maxSequence ? currentSequence : maxSequence];
    Arrays.fill(sequence, currentValue);
    return sequence;
}
```

Then:

```
int[] y = { 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7 };

int[] sequence = longestEqualSequence(y);

System.out.println("sequence=" + Arrays.toString(sequence) + ", size=" + sequence.length);
```

Output:

```
sequence=[4, 4, 4, 4], size=4
```

Comment: What If I wanted to print the longest sequence of numbers that are increasing in value? For Example, if my array int [ ] y = {6, 6, 4, 2, 9, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 5, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 5, 3} the longest sequence of numbers that are increasing in value are [2, 4, 6, 9]. How can I get this to be my desired output?

Comment: Can’t answer that in the comments. Ask a new question and I’ll try to help.